# How to start the same activity using startActivityForResult twice

Tags: android, start-activity

So I am trying to implement calling the same activity twice, I understand there will be better ways to do this but right now I just want 2 separate data recordings. When I try to run this code, the Diastolic BP gets read in first which is unintentional. Can someone explain why this is happening please. Thank you.

```
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                //The following is required when ^^^ this is used
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Please Read your Systolic Blood Pressure Value");
                startActivityForResult(i, SYSTOLIC_CHECK);
                //A different request code is required per activity called
                Intent j = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                j.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                j.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Please Read your Diastolic Blood Pressure Value");
                startActivityForResult(j, DIASTOLIC_CHECK);
```

...

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String thumbnailPath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_THUMBNAIL_FILE_PATH);
        String picturePath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_PICTURE_FILE_PATH);

        processPictureWhenReady(picturePath);
        // TODO: Show the thumbnail to the user while the full picture is being
        // processed.
    }
    else if ((requestCode == SYSTOLIC_CHECK) && resultCode == RESULT_OK)   {
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String spokenText = results.get(0);
        System.out.println("Systolic BP: " + spokenText);
        //OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(STORETEXT, 0));
    }
    else if ((requestCode == DIASTOLIC_CHECK) && resultCode == RESULT_OK)   {
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String spokenText = results.get(0);
        System.out.println("Diastolic BP: " + spokenText);
        //OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(STORETEXT, 0));
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: I think you can, just give seperate `requestCode`, then you get result based on the `requestCode`

Comment: Yes that's what I did in the code above ^^^. My issue is that they would be obtained in the wrong order, as the guys below me have explained, my code would carry on being executed in the calling activity as the second activity is opened.

Comment: Ok this is clear, just start one that you want to get result first, then call another activity from `onActivityResult` directly after you got first ´result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, since you call your Diastolic activity as last, this is laid over you systolic activity.
So you Diastolic Activity will be the one the user interacts with first.

I just want to point out that what @GreyBeardedGeek said is true.
It probably would be better if you just start you systolic activity, then, when you receive the result, start you Diastolic Activity (in OnActivityResult).

This will prevent issues with your activities not starting in the order you wanted.

**EDIT**

Your code would look something like this then

```
...else if ((requestCode == SYSTOLIC_CHECK) && resultCode == RESULT_OK)   {
    results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    String spokenText = results.get(0);
    System.out.println("Systolic BP: " + spokenText);
    //OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(STORETEXT, 0));

    //call second activity
    Intent j = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                j.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                j.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Please Read your Diastolic Blood Pressure Value");
                startActivityForResult(j, DIASTOLIC_CHECK);
} ...
```

**EDIT**

Your activity could look like this.

```
public class VoiceActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private String systole;
    private String diastole;

    private Button btnGetVoiceInput;

    private final int SYSTOLIC_CHECK=1, DIASTOLIC_CHECK=2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        btnGetVoiceInput = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVoiceInput);

        btnGetVoiceInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                 //The following is required when ^^^ this is used
                 i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                 i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Please Read your Systolic Blood Pressure Value");
                 startActivityForResult(i, SYSTOLIC_CHECK);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case SYSTOLIC_CHECK: {
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    systole = results.get(0);
                    System.out.println("Systolic BP: " + systole);

                    Intent j = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                    j.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                    j.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Please Read your Diastolic Blood Pressure Value");
                    startActivityForResult(j, DIASTOLIC_CHECK);
                }
                break;
            }
            case DIASTOLIC_CHECK: {
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    diastole = results.get(0);
                    Log.v("VoiceInput", "Diastolic BP: " + diastole);

                    doSomething();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        //do what you want with both readings here
        String bloodpressure = systole + " / " + diastole;
        Log.v("Bloodpressure", bloodpressure);
    }
}
```

After getting the 2 readings, you can do something with them.
This does still need some error handling, but I haven't used the voice input yet, so I don't know what values it returns/can return.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I am having issue with the "wait for it to return its result". I thought that once the startActivityForResult was called and the activity had its result, then onActivityResult would be called and nothing else would happen until it had returned. But this does not seem to be the case here?

Comment: Once you call `startActivityForResult`, all your code in the same function will still get executed before the new activity is opened.
You're code is not going to wait right after you call `startActivityForResult`

You shouldn't put any code after you start your new activity.

Once your new activity finishes, you will receive the result, and you can call your second activity.

Once your second activity finishes, you receive its result, and you can continue to do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: It is correct that your calling activity (activity1) will not wait for the second activity (activity2) to finish.
`StartActivity()` isn't a blocking method.
activity1 will continue it's lifecycle and go through it's `onPause()`
Once activity2 has finished, activity1 receive the result in `onActivityResult()` and then continue through it's `onResume()`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you SnyersK. Is there a simple way I can implement a blocking method? Or how could I develop code that would request audio input then request it again immediately afterwards (with a different question on the screen)? Put it in the answers and I can accept it as the answer

Comment: you can't write blocking code which starts a new activity and waits for it to finish.
You can't write blocking code on the UI thread at all, your application will crash if it takes too long. And even if it doesn't take long, you should not execute long running code on the UI thread.
If you do this, your application will have lags.
If you need to run blocking code (like a network request), you should always do this in a different thread. You can use multiple classes for this. AsyncTask and Service are a few examples.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question here though. I put an example for you. I put an example of what your code could look like in my answer.

Comment: This answer and comments are really great. Just one thing though, the code on the top of your answer makes sense, but the code below never seems to call startActivity for Diastolic? Wouldn't we need to add that to the SYSTOLIC_CHECK case as you mentioned in the code above?

Comment: I forget to add that indeed, sorry. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The API simply doesn't work that way - you can't queue up the launch multiple activities as you are trying to do.

The normal way to do this is to launch the first Activity with startActivityForResult, and when the first activity returns, launch the second one.

Comment: At what point does onActivityResult return then? I have read the documentation for onActivityResult but struggle to understand it

Comment: When you use startActivityResult, the starting Activity's onActivityResult method is invoked when the started Activity finishes.

Comment: I'm confused. So the onActivityResult is invoked when the activity finishes... So in my code, I call startActivityForResult for intent i, then onActivityResult is called, then after it is finished startActivityForResult is called again for intent j? Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes. You call startActivityForResult for Intent i, your onActivityResult gets called when Activity i finishes. You then call startActivityForResult for intent j, and your onActivityResult gets call again when Activity j finishes.